# Python 3.4 dictionary output different from python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, python-3.4

I am just learning Python so I would not be surprised if I am completely missing something here.  This is a BAM formatted sequencing file read in with fetch from pysam.  Everything works in python 2.7 in python 3.4 this code

```
consensus = readDict[dictTag][6][maxCig][2:]
print(consensus)
```

outputs this  `[b'GATC']` instead of the needed `['GATC']` from python 2.7

What is the root of the behavior and are their any solutions?

Comment: if you `print(consensus[0])` (the first item in your consensus-list), you won't notice the "b" any longer since it just indicates the type of the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 2.x `'GATC'` is a byte string and `u'GATC'` is a Unicode string.

In Python 3.x `'GATC'` is a Unicode string and `b'GATC'` is a byte string.

So you are getting the same result (byte string) in both cases.

You can decode the byte string to Unicode in Python 3.x to get the result you want:

```
>>> s = b'GATC'
>>> s
b'GATC'
>>> s.decode() # default UTF-8 decoding.
'GATC'
>>> s.decode('ascii')
'GATC'
```

#### Edit

Per the OP's comments below, here's another example:

```
>>> s=[b'GATC',b'CTAG'] # A list of byte strings
>>> s
[b'GATC', b'CTAG']
>>> s = [t.decode() for t in s] # decoding the list to Unicode
>>> s
['GATC', 'CTAG']
>>> for t in s:    # iterating over the strings and characters
...  for c in t:
...   print(t,c)
...
GATC G
GATC A
GATC T
GATC C
CTAG C
CTAG T
CTAG A
CTAG G
```

What you get if you skip the decode:

```
>>> s=[b'GATC',b'CTAG']
>>> for t in s:
...  for c in t:
...   print(t,c)
...
b'GATC' 71    # displays as byte strings and byte values (71 == ASCII 'G', etc.)
b'GATC' 65
b'GATC' 84
b'GATC' 67
b'CTAG' 67
b'CTAG' 84
b'CTAG' 65
b'CTAG' 71
```

Comment: Note that this difference in behavior is harmless. If you print those strings, the 'b's and 'u's disappear.

Comment: I am trying to take that string and do a for j in range(len(consensus) to go through each string one position at a time.  I like the decode idea if I can understand how to implement it.

Comment: @whereswalden: Not in Python 3 it is not. Printing a bytestring results in the `repr()` being written out. You'll need to decode to Unicode if you want it printed *as text*.

Comment: Thank you, you pointed me in the right direction. I was able to use this y = [unicode(i) for i in consensus] to get me what I needed.  Decode might be better but I keep getting a list has no attribute decode error.  I am learning.

Comment: Actually my solution does not work in python 3.4 so I am still out of luck.  Looks like I will stick with python 2.7 for now.

Comment: Mark T.  Thank you very much.  That was the exact solution I needed.  My mistake when I tried to decode was not to go through the list first.